# Как в Netbeans ставить комментарий вида /*… */ горячие клавиши?

Tags: java, netbeans

Либо я туплю, либо еще что, но не могу разобраться как в Netbeans поставить комментарий типа `/*… */` . Вроде и и-нет пролистал, ничего не нашел и пользователи особо о такой проблеме не пишут, хотя как мне кажется важный момент.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans может комментировать несколько строк, только с помощью `//`, не с `/*...*/`, используйте комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> или комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. Убирает комментарии на такую же комбинацию.

Вот список всех горячих клавиш, и не только - [тынц!](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf).

Comment: Там еще есть шаблон для Java кода bcom, но это такое.

Comment: Странно, такие  /*...*/ комментарии очень удобны для нескольких строк. Может их все таки как-то можно привязать к горячим клавишам?